# How load only some node fields?

Tags: 8, entities

`entity.query` service is very handy when it comes to finding nodes with specific field values. Unfortunately all it returns are entity IDs and revision IDs.

In case in which result set is big it's really inefficient to load whole nodes if only data from specific fields is needed.

In D7 it was possible for example to use `field_attach_load()` function which (thankfully) has been removed in D8, as detailed in [Fields are no longer handled individually and are bound to an entity type](https://www.drupal.org/node/2078765). The problem is that Drupal change log references `loadFieldItems()` and `doLoadFieldItems()` of `FieldableEntityStorageControllerBase` class neither of which exists in current release of D8.

What is the Drupal 8 way of loading data for specific node fields only?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Your title says, "load only some node fields" but then your last comment says, "loading data for specific node fields only." Does the latter mean you want to extract parts of the data array from a field?

Comment: @DannyEnglander I want to load only specific node fields. I don't want the whole node with all fields populated with data. For example: node has fields: body, image, color, date. And I want to know the value of color field only.

Comment: Assuming it's a node template for a specific content type, you can simply load the fields on their own. So instead of `{{ content }}`, you can do `{{ content.field_tags }}`.  If you do `{{ kint(content) }}`, you'll see the array of what is available to you.

Comment: I'm not talking about templating - his is PHP level. Let's assume that I have array with IDs of nodes and that I need to get values of  `color` and `image` fields for those nodes.

Comment: If you need to use PHP, you can do `kint($vars);` in a preprocess function (node for example) in your theme's .theme file to examine the array and then write code for what you need.

Comment: I don't want to var dump data Danny. I need to load this data for processing. I want to know how to load it with D8 APIs without having to load the whole node object.

Comment: The var dump using kint will help you extract the specific data you need to formulate your code but I guess I don't understand your question then, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38911/discussion-between-siliconmind-and-danny-englander).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Acquia articles](https://docs.acquia.com/articles) and specifically [this](https://docs.acquia.com/articles/drupal-8-loading-and-editing-fields):

> In Drupal 7, we often accessed fields directly, using hooks to modify
>   fields when they were loaded, changed, or saved. In Drupal 8, there is
>   a focus on entities instead of fields. **Because of this, if we want to
>   modify fields we need to get the fields out of the entities.**

So in [Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/8) you can't directly access any fields without first loading the whole entity as the following example (taken from the [Acquia article](https://docs.acquia.com/articles/drupal-8-loading-and-editing-fields)) demonstrates:

```
/**
* @var $entity \Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity
*/
$entity = $entity_storage->load($entity_id);


/**
* @var $field \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList
*/
$field = $entity->get($field_name);

// We get the string value from the field.
$value = $field->value;

// Get the summary from a body field.
$summary = $body_field->summary;

$field->value = 'changed value';
```

Unfortunately the specific thing you want doesn't exist in the API. All field data is loaded in bulk via `ContentEntityStorageBase::doLoadRevisionFieldItems`, and the standard `SqlContentEntityStorage` doesn't contain any methods for extracting individual fields. If you haven't already done so, it might be worth benchmarking this to see if there's a real problem. A lot of work was done on the cache system for D8, things might not be as slow as you think.

Implementing this manually would be pretty easy, just re-implement `SqlContentEntityStorage::buildQuery` in a new service class and change it to only load data for the field(s) passed in as an arguments from the table mapping. But you don't get any cache goodness with that, which I suspect is at least part of the reason loading individual fields was removed in the first place.

Comment: Not really helpful. I'm not looking for answer why it's not possible :) I'm looking for an answer how to tap into drupal core to load those fields manually. Fields inherit from `Map` which inherits from `TypedData`. There must be a way to create instance of a field class and load field data into it without having to load the whole node.

Comment: Fair enough. But what's the point in trying to do something that is not recommended or not even possible or violates the Drupal's standards, performance ? Keep in mind that everything depends on the way that Drupal stores data for each field - entity, the layers behind that mechanism and the provided API.

Comment: Why do think it violates anything? I'm trying to work around performance issues. It doesn't make sense to load 100 fully blown node objects just check values of one field for each of those nodes. And I do want to use API for that. If I wouldn't, I would write SQL queries to get that data, but that defeats the purpose of using drupal in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately what you want doesn't exist in the API @SiliconMind, I just spent a little bit checking. All field data is loaded in bulk via `ContentEntityStorageBase::doLoadRevisionFieldItems`, and the standard `SqlContentEntityStorage` doesn't contain any methods for extracting individual fields. If you haven't already done so, it might be worth benchmarking this to see if there's a real problem. A lot of work was done on the cache system for D8, things might not be as slow as you think

Comment: @Clive thanks for the explanation. Although it's a sad truth, your comment would be the answer to accept as it explains how fields are loaded today and why there is no way to load them individually.

Comment: I think I'd rather edit that bit in to this answer if you and @mchar are ok with that? This answer is very much the "why", the class references are really just the lower-level "how". By the way, implementing this manually would be pretty easy, just re-implement `SqlContentEntityStorage::buildQuery` in a new service class and change it to only load data for the field(s) passed in as an arguments from the table mapping. But you don't get any cache goodness with that, which I suspect is at least part of the reason loading individual fields was removed in the first place. I'm guessing though

Comment: @Clive It's fine by me, you may edit the answer, actually I'm happy that we managed to settle this. 
Also I agree between the distinction of "how" and "why" but the question was "What is the Drupal 8 way of loading data for specific node fields only?" 
so, I didn't make a deeper investigation like Clive did and that's absolutely right.

Comment: Fine by me. @Clive please include your explanation from the first comment and also the suggestion regarding `SqlContentEntityStorage::buildQuery` I think that would make for a perfect answer.

Answer (score 6):

I did some profiling with a query of 100,000 nodes, fetching the field `myfield` from all nodes of type `mybundle`.

## Good: A dynamic query with `addField()`

```
$connection = \Drupal::database();
$query = $connection->select('node__field_myfield');
$query->condition('node__field_myfield.bundle', 'mybundle');
$query->addField('node__field_myfield', 'field_myfield_value');
$result = $query->execute();
$values = $result->fetchAll();
```

This runs in about 250 milliseconds.

## Bad: An entity query with `loadMultiple()`

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('type', 'mybundle');
$node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
$values = [];
$nids = $query->execute();
$nodes = $node_storage->loadMultiple($nids);
foreach($nodes as $node) {
  $values[] = $node->get('field_myfield')->getValue();
}
```

This took 3 minutes after a few repeated attempts when the cache was fully built. After a cache rebuild, it took more than half an hour.

Comment: Small improvement to your "Good" - add language as part of the filtering.

Comment: "Good" with language would be `$query->condition('langcode', 'de');` or `$query->condition('langcode', $langcodes, 'IN');` for example. If you omit the language condition you'll have the resulting `$values` multiplied with the number of languages you have on your site.

Answer (score 0):

> In case in which result set is big it's really inefficient to load
>   whole nodes if only data from specific fields is needed.
>
> What is the Drupal 8 way of loading data for specific node fields
>   only?

uh...ummmm....[Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) with a filter **and/or** fixed contextual filter with allow multiple values checkmarked...

**Note:** Drupal 8 comes with views by default.

Answer (score -2):

Please create View/Reference/Block/Attachment with selected field. And Call that using contextual filter.

For example : 
http://localhost/project/admin/structure/views/view/view_machine_name/edit/your_block

```
            $nameshipped = 'view_machine_name'; // please check the url
            $viewshipped = views_get_view($nameshipped);
            $display_id_shipped = 'your_block';
            $viewshipped->set_display($display_id_shipped);
            //$viewshipped->set_arguments(array($all_con_id)); // if we need to use contextual filter.
            echo $html = $viewshipped->render();
```

Please use the above code where you want to implement.

Comment: I think the question makes it pretty clear what version of Drupal is being asked about - this is for Drupal 7, right?